# bash: raster2pgsql: command not found

Tags: postgis, debian

I'm using Debian 11 (bullseye) and have installed postgresql 13.5 and postgis 3.1.1 using synaptic package manager, `postgresql-13-postgis-3`

[image]

As far as I can tell everything is working but when I try to use raster2pgsql in terminal I get

```
raster2pgsql
bash: raster2pgsql: command not found
```

Do I need some additional packages or how can I fix it?

I have tried to find the executable with
`sudo find ~/ -name raster2pgsql` but nothing is found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether you have the `postgis` package installed.

I'm using the pgdg repository for PostgreSQL/PostGIS binaries on Debian 11 and have slightly different versions installed. I'm guessing the package structure may be similar. Looking at your question, I realized I also do not have raster2pgsql installed. I had the following packages installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep postgis
ii  postgresql-13-postgis-3            3.2.1+dfsg-1.pgdg110+1         amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 13
ii  postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts    3.2.1+dfsg-1.pgdg110+1         all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 13 -- SQL scripts
```

Looking into which package includes `raster2pgsql` suggested the `postgis` package (you can check that [here](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/postgis/filelist) - found by searching for "debian 11 postgis package"):

```
$ apt search raster2pgsql
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
postgis/bullseye-pgdg 3.2.1+dfsg-1.pgdg110+1 amd64
  Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL
$
```

Install `postgis` and check again:

```
sudo apt install postgis

...

$ which raster2pgsql
/usr/bin/raster2pgsql
$
```